# Cannot install RSOUND in racket 7.7 (DrRacket install: cannot find package on catalogs package: portaudio-x86_64-windows))

Tags: racket

I am using DR Racket 7.7 (installed via racket-7.7-x86_64-win32.exe) on Windows 10 and I have been unable to install rsound. I try to add the package with the packge installer and I am getting the following error message (the last line below):

```
Resolving "rsound" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/catalog/
Resolving "rsound" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Downloading repository github://github.com/jbclements/RSound/master/
00: Resolving "portaudio" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/catalog/
00: Resolving "portaudio" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Resolving "memoize" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/catalog/
Resolving "memoize" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Downloading repository github://github.com/jbclements/portaudio/master/
Downloading repository github://github.com/jbclements/memoize/master
Resolving "portaudio-x86_64-windows" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/catalog/
Resolving "portaudio-x86_64-windows" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Resolving "portaudio-x86_64-windows" via https://planet-compats.racket-lang.org
DrRacket install: cannot find package on catalogs
  package: portaudio-x86_64-windows
```

P.S. This is a fresh install, I have libportaudio 32 and 64 bit versions installed in the system folder. I also tried raco pkg install ... and am getting the same error.

Comment: Having the same issue. Someone has submitted a PR https://github.com/jbclements/portaudio/pull/11/files